# Html5 Audio Player Controls Not Working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

This is only happening on my computer. I tested it on other computers with latest version of chrome, and it works fine.

Testing Website:

http://template.webdvlm.com/content/index_full2.php

The player buttons are not working on chrome for me. When I click on play/next/volume, nothing happens. I see nothing in the log either. What could be the problem?

The player works fine on firefox on my computer.

I uninstalled/reinstalled chrome and still no fix.

Comment: Works fine for me after I choose a track to play. If I don't choose a track, the controls do't work.

Comment: same for me, but i tried it on a different laptop with latest chrome version, the controls work

Comment: no that means it works fine for you, even after clicking a track, the controls don't work for me